# How to do a redirect in a Sitecore Pipeline that does a 301?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I'm running some code as part of the httpRequestBegin pipeline in Sitecore to redirect if the URL is of a particular type.

I know that I need to use the [Sitecore WebUtil.Redirect() method](http://oscarcao.com/blog/2013/05/27/the-proper-way-of-handling-redirects-in-sitecore-cms) but this is redirecting with a status of 302. Is there any way I can do this as a 301 (permanent) redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [HttpResponse.RedirectPermanent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd322042%28VS.100%29.aspx) method that was introduced in .NET 4.0, No sitecore API needed

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use Sitecore's WebUtil. Just Response.Redirect after setting the statuscode

Comment: Is there not an issue with doing that when using this in Sitecore Pipelines? http://oscarcao.com/blog/2013/05/27/the-proper-way-of-handling-redirects-in-sitecore-cms

Comment: This answer is correct. And no, there is not issue with that in your processor. You may need to do something like `args.Response.Redirect(...)`

Answer (score 1):

This [blogpost](http://www.partechit.nl/nl/blog/2012/11/return-404-status-code-when-itemnotfound-page-is-loaded) might help you out. It is about handling the 404 redirect from Sitecore but it's handling it in the same way you can do with a 301 redirect I guess

Answer (score 1):

To ensure a 301 response code, use:

args.Response.RedirectPermanent